# Sorting vs iterative querying question in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I recently picked up a project a little out of my comfort zone and I'm not sure how to approach part of it. This may be a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find any solid answers in my searching. I've worked in other languages, but am new to python/pandas which is what I'm being requested to do this in.

My end goal is an automated script to send out an "In Approval" table to managers of all active orders waiting to be approved. The part I'm having issues with is tackling the actual data. I import the data from a CSV, and my initial plan was to break different columns of the CSV into 2 dataframes. 1 with the active approvals and 1 with all the order data. I was then going to iterate through the Approvals based on a unique ID and run it through a class that queries and returns orders matching that ID. Then I found out that Pandas doesn't iterate like I'm used to in other languages, where I'd just run it through a ForEach.

So my question would be, is there a best known method to iterate through and query data like this, or is there some Pandas magic I'm missing that will allow me to sort and pull out data I can format into an HTML table for presentation?

**EDIT**
Here is a simplified and bleached version of the data I'm working with and what I'm trying to turn it into. I did this as a table for ease of readability.

| Approval_Id | Approval_Status | Approver_Status | Approver_Type | Approver_Name | Receiver | Total_Cost | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1138 | ACTIVE | Approved | Manager | Krabs, Eugene | SquarePants, SpongeBob | 26375 | Network Gear |
| 1138 | ACTIVE | Approved | Manager | Krabs, Eugene | SquarePants, SpongeBob | 26375 | PC Gear |
| 1138 | ACTIVE | Awaiting Approval | Finance | Hira, Jeffery | SquarePants, SpongeBob | NA | Network Gear |
| 1138 | ACTIVE | Awaiting Approval | Finance | Hira, Jeffery | SquarePants, SpongeBob | NA | PC Gear |
| 1138 | ACTIVE | To be approved | Signature Authority | Pennyworth, Alfred | SquarePants, SpongeBob | NA | Network Gear |
| 1138 | ACTIVE | To be approved | Signature Authority | Pennyworth, Alfred | SquarePants, SpongeBob | NA | PC Gear |
| 1138 | ACTIVE | To be approved | Signature Authority | Pines, Stan | SquarePants, SpongeBob | NA | Network Gear |
| 1138 | ACTIVE | To be approved | Signature Authority | Pines, Stan | SquarePants, SpongeBob | NA | PC Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Finance | Hira, Jeffery | Omashu, Bumi | NA | Network Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Finance | Hira, Jeffery | Omashu, Bumi | NA | PC Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Finance | Hira, Jeffery | Omashu, Bumi | NA | Other |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Manager | Kuei, Earth King | Omashu, Bumi | 194485 | Network Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Manager | Kuei, Earth King | Omashu, Bumi | 194485 | PC Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Manager | Kuei, Earth King | Omashu, Bumi | 194485 | Other |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Signature Authority | Pennyworth, Alfred | Omashu, Bumi | NA | Network Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Signature Authority | Pennyworth, Alfred | Omashu, Bumi | NA | PC Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Signature Authority | Pennyworth, Alfred | Omashu, Bumi | NA | Other |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Signature Authority | Pines, Stan | Omashu, Bumi | NA | Network Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Signature Authority | Pines, Stan | Omashu, Bumi | NA | PC Gear |
| 6585 | APPROVED | Approved | Signature Authority | Pines, Stan | Omashu, Bumi | NA | Other |

I'm looking to return the ACTIVE rows under Approval_Status and get rid of the duplicate entries out of the Approver columns, while grabbing only a single copy of the number out of the Total_Cost. This is what I want to end state to look like:

| Approval_Id | Approver_Status | Approver_Type | Approver_Name | Receiver | Total_Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1138 | Approved | Manager | Krabs, Eugene | SquarePants, SpongeBob | 26375 |
| 1138 | Awaiting Approval | Finance | Hira, Jeffery | SquarePants, SpongeBob | 26375 |
| 1138 | To be approved | Signature Authority | Pennyworth, Alfred | SquarePants, SpongeBob | 26375 |
| 1138 | To be approved | Signature Authority | Pines, Stan | SquarePants, SpongeBob | 26375 |

Comment: You can iterate over a column of a dataframe with standard python for x in y. You can also iterate over the entire dataframe with iterrows or itertuples.

Comment: Python's `for` is analogous to `foreach` in other languages so if you're familiar with it then just iterate using for, although I would recommend looking at some vectorized functions included with Pandas, things like `groupby` might be useful in your project. Can't say more without seeing what your data looks like.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your concrete problem. A [mcve] would be ideal. Consult [the following quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for how to make reproducible pandas examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you ask, split into a filter, colun selection and duplicate dropping operations for clarity:

```
df = df.loc[df.Approval_Status == "ACTIVE"]
df = df["Approval_Id", "Approver_Status", "Approver_Type", "Approver_Name", "Receiver", "Total_Cost"]
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you!